# Sound problem with tvtime in kubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: sound, kubuntu

I have an issue with tvtime, my tv card is a Hauppauge hvr-1850 and the sound card is the one builted on the motherboard which is an ASUS P5Q Pro Turbo with a VIA VT1708S Audio Chipset. I get a perfect image in tvtime but no sound, but if I start tvtime with the "tvtime | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -" command then I get a perfect image and sound but when I close tvtime the sound keeps running it doesn't shut off with the tvtime application. Does anybody know how to fix this? I would relly like to make this work and only keep Kubuntu on my PC as my main OS. Regards, Michel

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing more information! Can you tell us a bit more about your TV card and sound card? More information is required. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question to provide all details requested and anything else you can think of that might be relevant. I thank you and the community thanks you!

Comment: Hi,My tv card is a Hauppauge hvr-1850 and the sound card is the one builted on the motherboard which is an ASUS P5Q Pro Turbo with a VIA VT1708S Audio Chipset. I get a perfect image in tvtime but no sound, but if I start tvtime with the "tvtime | arecord -D hw:1,0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -" command tehn I get a perfect image and sound bvut when I close tvtime the sound keeps running it doesn't shut off with the tvtime application. Thank you, Michel